# Animated 1990s sci-fi tv series - Jupiter-based space fighters with orange lasers

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime

In the mid-late 90s I caught a show on the now long gone British TV channel "Super Channel". It was a show that took place in our solar system (I specifically remember a base in orbit around Jupiter) that seemed to be about two factions fighting for control.

The quality of the animation was "Transformers +". I also remember the lasers on the ships' wings being orange and attached to discs, making them movable. That color made me think at the time that they were part of a toy line, but I never saw any in the shops.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBC_Europe

Answer (score 3):

I think that the show you are describing may be "Starcom: The US Space Force".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starcom:_The_U.S._Space_Force

and

http://futurewarstories.blogspot.com/2011/09/msf-oddities-starcom-us-space-force.html

Most of the active weapons for the vehicles were a bright orange color in animation and on the toys - the laser weaponry on the Human space-fighter craft did appear to be mounted to the airframe in a disc-shapped manner.

The series explored most of our solar system, and one episode *Fire and Ice* (http://www.tv.com/shows/starcom/fire-and-ice-153673/) did feature a battle near Jupiter, near a base on the moon of Io.

Comment: Thanks - that's the one! I've been thinking about that show for 20 years!

Comment: @Peter Eliasson, glad I could be of help. I remember it here in the states, it only had a limited run in my area. Please mark this one as answered!